# How Generate the StringBuffer(structure) from the Given List<Beans>

Tags: java, list

I have a very big and silly problem, i have to generate one String Buffer from the following List of Beans

```
[{STATE=-1, LEVEL=1, LABELS=Institution Management, ICON=DOWN, DATA=null}, 
{STATE=-1, LEVEL=2, LABELS=Billing of Services, ICON=DOWN, DATA=null}, 
{STATE=-1, LEVEL=3, LABELS=Maintenance, ICON=DOWN, DATA=null}, 
{STATE=-1, LEVEL=4, LABELS=Maintain Agency Billing Profile, ICON=APP, DATA=OBMABILP}, 
{STATE=-1, LEVEL=2, LABELS=Dietary Restrictions, ICON=DOWN, DATA=null}, 
{STATE=-1, LEVEL=3, LABELS=Offender Dietary Restrictions, ICON=APP, DATA=OIDREMEA}, 
{STATE=-1, LEVEL=1, LABELS=Community Management, ICON=DOWN, DATA=null}, 
{STATE=-1, LEVEL=2, LABELS=Primary Officer / Agent Assignment, ICON=DOWN, DATA=null}, 
{STATE=-1, LEVEL=3, LABELS=External Ownership Transfers, ICON=APP, DATA=OCDEXPOW}, 
{STATE=-1, LEVEL=2, LABELS=Case Management, ICON=DOWN, DATA=null}, 
{STATE=-1, LEVEL=3, LABELS=Contact Log, ICON=APP, DATA=OCDCLOGS}]
```

I Should Create the Following StringBuffer

```
 [
    {
        name:"Institution Management",
            menuItems:[
                {name:"Billing of Services",
                menuItems:[{
                name:"Maintenance"
                    menuItems:[{
                        name:"OBMABILP"  
                    }]
                }]
                menuItems:[
                {name:"Dietary Restrictions",
                    menuItems:[
                        {name:"OIDREMEA"}
                    ]                   
                }]              
            }]
    },
    {
        name:"Community Management",
            menuItems:[{
                name:"Primary Officer / Agent Assignment",
                    menuItems:[
                    {name:"OCDEXPOW"}
                    ]
            }]
            menuItems:[
                {name:"Case Management",
                menuItems:[
                    {name:"OCDLOGS"}
                ]
            }]
    }
]
```

I have developed the following Method (not mandatory to use this), you can provide your own mehthod that method able to generate the Given StringBuffer

```
public String generate_Json_For_Dynamic_Menu_Data(List<DynamicMenuItems> menuList) {
    List<DynamicMenuItems> menuList1 = menuList;
    StringBuffer menuBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    menuBuffer.append("[ \n");  
    for(int i = 0; i < menuList1.size(); i++){
        DynamicMenuItems bean = new DynamicMenuItems();
        if(bean.getData() == null) {
            menuBuffer.append("{name:'"+bean.getLabels()+"',\n");
        }
        else{
            menuBuffer.append("menuItems:[\n");
            menuBuffer.append("{name:'"+bean.getData()+"'},");
        }
    }
    return menuBuffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: So, what doesn't work in your solution?

Comment: thanks for you comment, provided java method not generating exact StringBuffer(Indentation is not required)

Comment: Can you post the output your method is currently providing? And please highlight where it differentiates from the desired output.

Comment: Also, please be more specific on how and by what rules the given input should generate the desired output. I see a hierarchy in the output but where is it in the input? Please clearly specify that.